# simple java regular expression not working

Tags: java, regex

I have this simple example of a regular expression. But it is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
String name = "abc";
System.out.println(name.matches("[a-zA-Z]"));
```

it returns false, it should be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use :

```
name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") // matches more than one character
```

or `name.matches("\\w+")` `// matches more than one character`

```
name.matches("[a-zA-Z]") // matches exactly one character.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `+` to your regex to match one or more alphabets,

```
String name = "abc"; System.out.println(name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

Your regex `[a-zA-Z]` must match a single alphabet, not more than one.

`[a-zA-Z]` Match a lowercase alphabet from `a-z` or match an uppercase alphabet from `A-Z`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this evaluates to false is, it tries to match *the entrie string* (see doc of `String.matches()`) to the Pattern `[A-Za-z]` wich only matches a single character. Either use
`Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]").matcher(str).find()` to see if a substring matches (will return true in this case), or alter the RegEx to account for multiple Characters. The cleanest way of doing so is

```
Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]+$");
```

The `^` marks "start of string" and `$` marks "end of string". `+` means "previous token at least once".

If you want to allow the empty String as well, use

```
Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]*$");
```

instead (* means "match the previous token 0 or more times")

Answer (score 1):

Try with `[a-zA-Z]+`

[image]

`[a-zA-Z]` indicates:

[image]

Comment: Nice visualisation. Where did you get these from?

Comment: @AlexR From regexper.com